# ionic missing script: ionic:build

Tags: ionic-framework, npm-scripts

I am trying to build an ionic app, however when I run `npm run ionic:build -–prod`, I get the following error:

```
npm run ionic:build -–prod
npm ERR! Darwin 17.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:build" "-–prod"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: ionic:build
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Using the following versions:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

Quick search suggested running `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` which I did, however that did not solve the issue.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried running `npm run build` instead?

Comment: @Phonolog that works. Do you know why that is the case? Also if you can post that an answer with the reason behind it, that would be great.

Comment: Hmm actually those two should be synonyms, but to be sure you'll have to check your `package.json`, where your npm scripts are defined...

Answer (score 3):

I started my Ionic 4 app from a blank starter and the scripts to run are in the Ionic json.

If you `npm run build`, should work for you.

Comment: Work for me. I'm using Ionic 5.4.6

Answer (score 3):

Update the project's `package.json` file script section like this:

```
"scripts" : { 
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",  
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve" 
}
```